# Simplify the formula for the number of distributions leaving none of the $n$ cells empty

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I'd like to help with the following problem:

> $$ \binom{x}{r-1} + \binom{x}{r} = \binom{x+1}{r} \tag{8.6}\label{8.6} $$
>   7. Let $A(r, n)$ be the number of distributions leaving *none of the n cells
>   empty*. Show by a combinatorial argument that
>   $$ A(r, n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^r \binom{r}{k} A(r-k, n) \tag{11.5}\label{11.5} $$
>   Conclude that
>   $$ A(r, n) = \sum_{v=0}^n (-1)^v \binom{n}{v} (n-v)^r \tag{11.6}\label{11.6} $$
>   Hint: Use induction; assume $\ref{11.6}$ to hold and express $A(r-k,n)$ in
>   $\ref{11.5}$ accordingly. Change the order of summation and use the binomial
>   formula **to express $A(r, n+1)$ as the difference of two simple sums**. Replace in the second sum $v+1$ by a new index of summation and use $\ref{8.6}$.

According to the Hint:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A(r, n+1)
&=& \sum_{k=1}^r \binom{r}{k} \sum_{v=0}^n (-1)^v \binom{n}{v} (n-v)^{r-k} \\
&=& \sum_{v=0}^n (-1)^v \binom{n}{v} \sum_{k=1}^r \binom{r}{k} (n-v)^{r-k} \\
&=& \sum_{v=0}^n (-1)^v \binom{n}{v} (n-v+1)^r \tag{*}\label{*} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I'm now stuck on this.

I've tried to evaluate the $A(r,n)$ for $n=4$ and $n=5$, and noticed that the expression could perhaps be split by the value of $(-1)^v$:

$$
A(r, n) =
\sum_{v=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2v} (n+1-2v)^r -
\sum_{v=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2v+1} (n-2v)^r
$$

But this seems to be *wrong* because of the floor function and I don't know where to go from there either. Into which simple sums can I split $\ref{*}$ please?

There are other question about this number but I'm interested only in the bold part in the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your mistake:
$$
\sum_{v=0}^n (-1)^v \binom{n}{v} \sum_{k=1}^r \binom{r}{k} (n-v)^{r-k} 
= \sum_{v=0}^n (-1)^v \binom{n}{v} [(n-v+1)^r-(n-v)^r],
$$
because in the binomial formula the index runs from **zero** to $r$ while here it starts at $k=1$, so you have to subtract the $k=0$ term.